# Magical Evening

Tags: mathematics

Tonight will be a magical evening full of fun and excitement if you can figure out this riddle.

> When the clock strikes nine but loose three dash you will find a feast at the seven of these. Where he is one of his kind and 11,13,17 share this name.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Just to clarify, did you mean 'lose' or 'loose' and 'dash' or 'dashes' ? Also if you're interested in getting your first badge and learning about the site try taking the tour : https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @gabbo1092 No need to fix a grammatical error if you're just turning it into *another* grammatical error :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor My bad guess I didn't read carefully enough. Thanks for fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

The feast is...

> at 19:00 (7:00 PM). The "three dash" here might mean modular arithmetic. 9 o'clock can be 09:00 or 21:00, the latter of which is equivalent to 9 o'clock mod 12. We can either go from 09:00 to 21:00 or vice-versa (yay nightlife). 11, 13 and 17 are primes. The prime hours between 09:00 and 21:00 are 11, 13, 17 and 19 o'clock. They're 23, 2, 3, 5 and 7 if we go the other way around. However, "the one of a kind" one is implied to be somewhat unique compared to 11, 13 and 17 (at least when they're ruled out/eliminated), so it must be 19.